# Do Not load data without input url parameters angular/.Net

Tags: .net, angular

i have create an api and displaying data from it using angular. i have created an input and button, when we input model and click on button it shows relevant data perfectly, but problem is that when we only click button it shows all data from api becuase of url address (https://localhost:5001/api/Machines/), what should i do that only +Model should run, not previous all data.

**comp.ts**

```
Model='';
searchMachine(){
  this.SpinnerService.show(); 
  this.http
    .get("https://localhost:5001/api/Machines/"+this.Model.trim())
    .subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data)
      this.userdata=data;
      this.SpinnerService.hide();  
    })
}
```

**comp.html**

```
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="Model" (keyup.enter)="searchMachine()" >
  <button type="submit" (click)=searchMachine() >Find Model</button>
```

**List in .Net**

```
public List<Machines> Gets()
{
    using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@Model", Model);

        var oMachine = con.Query<Machines>("spGetMacDetailsByName", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        return oMachine.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you log the modal data on button click?

Comment: Please share the store procedure as well so we can see what is going on in store procedure

Comment: `ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetMacDetailsByID]   --spGetMacDetailsByID null,'PC122'
    
@Model as nvarchar(300)=null    


as
begin
   select 
   * from 
        MachineDetails 
    where Model = @Model

end`

Comment: stored procedure is simple. it just input the parameters such as Model

Comment: You must add a validation on button click to pass the model is compulsory then it will work fine. Your store procedure is simple if there is no parameter then it must not return any record.

Comment: how to do that please help, html,ts file is above

Answer (score 0):

You can check model by doing this

```
  searchMachine(){
        console.log(this.Model)
    
    if(!this.Model){
    alert('please enter model');
    return false;
    }
            this.SpinnerService.show(); 
            this.http.get("https://localhost:5001/api/Machines/"+this.Model.trim()).subscribe(data =>{
              console.log(data)
              this.userdata=data;
              this.SpinnerService.hide();  
                })
            }
```

Comment: now i input model but it showing please enter model on alert

Comment: it still return on empty input, but when input model it showing please enter

Comment: Please look into the updated code

Comment: now its working, by doing this `if(!this.Model)`